# Summarizing records by date in Rails 3 ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a large table with many records that share a timestamp. I want to get a result set that has a column summed by timestamp. I see how you can simply use the 'sum' method to get a columns total. I need to, however, group by a date column. This is far less obvious. I know I can use 'find_by_sql' but it will be hideous to code as I have to do this for over 20 columns. I assume AR must have some magic to do this which escapes me?

Date set example:

table/model: games/Game

```
player_name, points_scored, game_date
john, 20, 08-20-2012
sue, 30, 08-20-2012
john, 12, 08-21-2012
sue, 10, 08-21-2012
```

What i want to see in my results is:

```
game_date, total_points
08-20-2012, 50
08-21-2012, 22
```

Here is a crude example of what the SQL query would look like:

```
SELECT game_date, SUM(points_scored)
FROM games
GROUP BY game_date
```

Mind you, I actually have 20 'score' columns to SUM by timestamp.

How can I simply use AR to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It took some digging and playing around but I figured it out. I was hoping to find something better than 'find_by_sql' and I did, but it isn't a whole lot better. Again, knowing that I need to SUM 20+ columns by timestamp, here is the solution in the context of the example above.

```
results = Game.select( 'game_date, SUM(points_scored) as "points_scored"').group( 'game_date' )
```

Now, that doesn't look so bad, but I have to type in the 20+ SUM() within that 'select' method. Doesn't save a whole lot of work from 'find_by_sql' but it works.